# Expect - Different timeout for expect_user and expect?

Tags: expect

I'd like have an unlimited (or very large) timeout for `expect_user` and the default timeout for `expect`. Is there a way to set different timeouts? Or would I just have to manually do it before every change in usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `expect` and `expect_user` support  the `-timeout` option. Usually I would set the default timeout value in the `timeout` var and use the `-timeout` option for `expect_user`. For example:

```
set timeout 30; # the default timeout value

# don't time out when waiting for user's input
expect_user -timeout 100000 -re "(.*)\n"; # use -1 for infinite timeout
set user_input "$expect_out(1,string)"
```